# Move div with scrollbar inside a fixed div

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, css-position

I have a div on my page (let's call it div A) which is `position:fixed` and that's fine. However, within that div I have several other divs (let's called them divs 1, 2 & 3) which I want to move as the visitor uses the scrollbar.

How can I tell divs 1, 2 & 3 to follow the scrollbar position?

HTML:

```
<section class="block">
  <div class="full-width blue">
  </div>

  <div class="full-width green">
  </div>

  <div class="full-width orange">
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.block{
    width: 300px;
    height: 104px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The `.full-width` class just tells the divs to run the full width of their container.

Comment: Could you post an image of the desired outcome?

Comment: @FFrewin Sample code now added.

Comment: @PeterButcher in the long run I'm thinking of using an SVG graphic as a mask (I know not all browsers support this) to 'reveal' the coloured blocks beneath it. Above is just a proof of concept to get it working.

Comment: @Toby I'll knock up a possible solution in jsfiddle

Comment: Okay, current sample code didn't help much. The divs inside the fixed positioned div, will keep also their position when scrolling down. Yet, it's not that clear what you want to do. Just noticed that you have a jQuery tag for the question. Is this some kind of effect you are after?

Comment: When you say "move as the visitor uses the scrollbar" - in what direction?  I updated my answer below and added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

**HTML**

```
<section class="block">
    <div class="full-width blue">
    </div>

    <div class="full-width green">
    </div>

    <div class="full-width orange">
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.block{
    width: 300px;
    height: 104px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #CCC;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.full-width {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 104px;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #00CCFF;
}
.green {
    background-color: #CCFF00;
}
.orange {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmy6g8v2/

Or like this?:

I have slightly modified the fiddle supplied by @deebs

http://jsfiddle.net/0h6fuyb2/1/

Comment: Thanks for that @PeterButcher, but I don't want the scrollbars within the `.block` div - I need `.block` to remain fixed, but its contents to move with the main scrollbar.

Comment: Ah righto. You'll need some JQuery to alter the scrolling of this div depending on the scroll position of the main page.

Comment: @Toby Check out my latest edit, the fiddle at the bottom

Comment: You may need to modify the full-width div heights to your exact liking but it basically works.

Comment: Great - thanks to @deebs for the initial fiddle, and yourself for adapting it. This works great! Thanks guys =)

Comment: Great work Peter - and no offense here @Toby, but what should be the answer:  the adaptation or the process?

Comment: That's a very good question @deebs. I'm a bit of a stackoverflow noob, so I'm not sure of the correct etiquette with regards to answers. I'm guessing I can't flag two answers as correct, so any guidance appreciated if I need to make a change.

Comment: Hey - it's no problem at all. Ultimately the goal is for users (noobs like us and old-timers alike) to get the information they need. What you did is fine, that's your judgment call. Typically anything helpful along the way gets credit if possible too. And @PeterButcher - thanks! Next time I'll buy

Answer (score 1):

What if you do something like this to get the scrollheight then match up css of the colored divs, or even a container wrapping those divs with that scrollheight:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
    function scrollFunction() {
        var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
        var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
        $('.blue').css("margin-top", top) 
    }
});
```

*REVISED CODE*

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yLn7ux4/) but I'm not sure this is the "scroll matching" that you want.

Comment: Still not sure on the visual behavior you want of those colored divs, but here is another option:  http://jsfiddle.net/yL02ubrf/

Comment: That's really close, @deebs! How can I make `.blue` move in the opposite direction? So that it moves with the rest of the page content and not the scrollbar itself?

Answer (score 0):

U should use `overflow:scroll;` to include all the divs inside the wrapper with the scroll property.
Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7k3nvkx/) to see a working example.

If u don't want to see a scrollbar, this is another solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/yx68daf8/)

Hope it useful!

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he is looking for... I think he wants the colors to scroll as the main scroolbar for the page is scrolled

Comment: Yeah, not quite @user1038382 - I don't want the scrollbars inside the `.block` div, but for the contents of `.block` to move with the main scrollbar. Thanks for trying!